# Can I choose $k+1$ hypersurfaces to avoid a fiber of dimension $k$ in projective space?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a closed subscheme of dimension $k$ in $\mathbb{P}^n_A$, where $A$ is a Noetherian ring. In Exercise 11.3.C of Ravi Vakil's notes, it is shown that one may choose $k+1$ hypersurfaces such that the intersection of these hypersurfaces avoids $X$. This uses Krull's Principal Ideal Theorem, which is why $A$ must be Noetherian.

Let $\pi: X\rightarrow \text{Spec}(A)$ be the structure morphism.

My question is this: If $p$ is a point of $\text{Spec}(A)$, and $\pi^{-1}(p) \subset X$ is the fiber of $p$ in $X$ of dimension $r$, can I still find $r+1$ hypersurfaces whose intersection avoids the fiber? If $p$ is closed this would be immediate as then the fiber is closed, but in general this will not be true.

Note that my question is inspired from this [Upper semicontinuity of fibre dimension on the target](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/956335/upper-semicontinuity-of-fibre-dimension-on-the-target), where showing one can avoid a fiber of a given dimension is crucial to showing upper semicontinuity of fiber dimension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is more or less a copy of part of my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/956335/upper-semicontinuity-of-fibre-dimension-on-the-target), which I copied over rather than just linked to since that answer contains a lot of material irrelevant to this question. I also don't think that either question is a duplicate of the other, this question is interesting even without applying it to the linked one.

Since $\pi: X \rightarrow \operatorname{Spec}(A)$ factors through $\mathbb{P}_A^n$, the map $\pi^{-1}(p)\rightarrow \operatorname{Spec(\kappa(p))}$ factors through $\mathbb{P}_{\kappa(p)}^n$, and since $X \rightarrow \mathbb{P}_A^n$ is a closed embedding, so is $\pi^{-1}(p)\rightarrow \mathbb{P}_{\kappa(p)}^n$:
$$
\require{AMScd} \begin{CD}
    \pi^{-1}(p) @>>>\mathbb{P}_{\kappa(p)}^n@>>>\operatorname{Spec}(\kappa(p))
    \\ @VVV @VVV @VVV\\
    X @>>> \mathbb{P}_A^n @>>> \operatorname{Spec}(A)
    \end{CD}
$$
But now $\pi^{-1}(p)$ is a closed subscheme of $\mathbb{P}_{\kappa(p)}^n$, of dimension $\leq r$, and so we may find $r+1$ hypersurfaces $H'_i$ in $\mathbb{P}_{\kappa(p)}^n$ such that $\pi^{-1}(p)\cap_i H'_i = \phi$. We can now take hyperpsurfaces $H_i \subset \mathbb{P}_A^n$ that have pre-image $H'_i$ in $\mathbb{P}_{\kappa(p)}^n$ (We can choice some lift of the defining equation of the hyperplanes as polynomials in $\kappa(p)$ to polynomials in $A$). Then it must be the case that $\pi^{-1}(p)\cap_i H_i = \phi$.